# Как правильно: "в Бабьем Яре" или "в Бабьем Яру"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет об известном топониме, то "в Бабьем Яре". Форма "в ... Яру" могла появиться под действием местной формы предложного падежа слова "яр" (на яру), но употребление таких вариантов не распространяется на топонимы.